# Copy value in Open Office Calc

Tags: copy-paste, csv, openoffice-calc

I have a handful of cells in several spreadsheets that contain `=AVERAGE(<some range>)`  and when I try to copy them into another spreadsheet I just copy the function and get `#REF!`.

Is there any way to copy values?  If it matters I'm using csv files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy them, then Right click -> Paste special, tick "Numbers" and hit enter.

Comment: Also my favourite way of Paste Special is `Shift+Ctrl+v` - very handy and quick/